# Any two topological structure on a set X are related by a bijection?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

[In a book I read the following statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muze4.png)

The statement

> "Any two topological structures on $X$, equivalent or not, are related to ono another trough a bijection"

Is strange to me!

For example, if a  take a set $A = {x,y}$

Two examples of topology over $A={x,y}$ are

$\tau_a = \{\phi, \{x, y\}\} $

and

$\tau_b = \{\phi, \{x, y\}, \{x\}, \{y\} \} $

How can there be a bijection between the topologies? They do not have the same number of elements

Comment: Notice that the bijection is from $X \to X$.

Comment: I have no idea what the author wants to say with "related to one another through a bijection". They can't possibly mean that any two topological structures on a set $X$ are homeomorphic, but what else could they mean?

Comment: How they might be related would change with the bijection, would it not?  However, the identity could be selected as the bijection.  The statement makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks @SahibaArora. But I still can not understand why always  will exist  a bijection between these  topologies

Comment: Bijection is just a one-one, onto function. Take the identity map from $X \to X$. It will be a bijection irrespective of the topology.

Comment: @messias  The bijection is not between the topologies;  it is between the sets of points of the spaces.

Comment: It seems very strange that you are asking a problem you are having with a book you are reading, BUT YOU DO NOT TELL US WHAT BOOK THAT IS. If you were having a problem with your car, and asking for help on cars.SE, would you not state the make and morel and year of your car?

Comment: You identify the book only as "a book I read". Perhaps, if you look towards the front of the book, you will be able to find a title, an author, a publisher, a publication date, an ISBN?

Comment: @bof: Googling for "any two topological structures equivalent or not" revealed [this book](https://books.google.sk/books?id=ydrzCAAAQBAJ). The sentence is on page 390.

Comment: @PeterElias Good find. It still seems utterly bizarre that the OP would withhold that information.